# no python3 support for brew macvim

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, macvim

For some reason macvim installed with brew doesn't have the python3 support. Here is how I installed it:

```
brew install macvim --with-cscope --with-python3
```

Whenever I run

```
:echo has('python3')
```

The result is 0, meaning there is no python3 support. Does anybody know what is the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 is deliberately disabled in the macvim recipe in homebrew.

You can, however, run "brew edit macvim" and fix up the recipe so it works.

I recommend the following actions (which have worked for me):

- Use the current MacVim 7.4 snapshot 72 (update the url and sha1).  brew still has older snapshot 71.
- sha1 '3fb5b09d7496c8031a40e7a73374424ef6c81166'
- Delete all the patches from the end of the recipe.  The last line should be `__END__`.  None of the patches are necessary anymore - ruby support was fixed upstream in snapshot 72.
- depends_on :python3 => :recommended
- in the install function, when its messing with the args, fixup the python section like so:

  ```
  args << "--enable-python3interp=yes" if build.with? 'python3'
  ENV.prepend 'LDFLAGS', "-L#{python3.libdir} -F#{python3.framework} -framework Ruby" if python3 && python3.brewed?
  ```

Ensure you use a homebrew python3 and if you have upgraded to Mavericks, re-brew absolutely everything - the stdc++ library has changed and you cannot mix old and new when linking.

brew it with:
`$ brew install --HEAD macvim`

`$ mvim --version`   # to ensure it has all the right things linked

I've run through ultisnips and vinarise, both of which work and neither of which caused the window to mysteriously disappear as previously lamented in the recipe for macvim & python3.  I've also done other basic testing with :py3 command.  No issues seen (yet)